# I Found old wallet but there is new mined transactions but unconfirmed

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet, unconfirmed-transactions, balance

the wallet is old
but transactions are new 2020
transactions type : mined
unconfirmed[image]

Comment: What is that?????????

Answer (score 1):

Those are orphaned blocks, it means while you were mining that block someone else mined it faster than you, thus you do not get the credit for those mined blocks.

Comment: He's mining 11 blocks in 17 minutes (a magnitude faster than the entire network combined). His block subsidy is completely off. I think there is far more wrong here than just some orphaning. My guess is that this is broken software, or at least not Bitcoin.